# Gravar um valor padrão no banco de dados, caso o dado seja omitido

Tags: php, mysql

Criei um banco de dados e estou enviando as informações normalmente. Porém, eu tenho um campo opcional no formulário. Caso o usuário queira informar mais detalhes, ele escreve normalmente, caso não, eu queria que enviasse a seguinte mensagem para o banco de dados `Sem Mensagem`.

```html
<?php

$user = $_POST["user2"];
$manga = $_POST["titulo2"];
$capitulo = $_POST["capitulo2"];
$mensagem = $_POST["mensagem2"];
$assunto = $_POST["opcoes"];

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","report");
$sql = "insert into denuncia values(null,'".$user."','".$manga."','".$capitulo."','".if($mensagem == 0){"Sem mensagem"} else {$mensagem}."','".$assunto."')";



if(mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {

    $msg = "Obrigado! Sua denúncia foi enviada.";
} else {
    $msg = "Erro ao enviar.";
}


mysqli_close($con);

?>

<script> alert('<?php echo $msg;?>');
    location.href="index.php";
    </script>
```

Comment: Qual é o campo opcional?

Answer (score 5):

Ignorando os problemas de segurança existentes.

Por mim você tem quatro alternativas fácies:

1. Definir como "DEFAULT" no MySQL.
2. Definir no INSERT no PHP.
3. Definir o texto como saída no PHP.
4. Definir o texto como saída no MySQL.

---

### Definir DEFAULT no MySQL:

```
ALTER TABLE denuncia MODIFY COLUMN coluna VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Sem mensagem';
```

Então poderia fazer o `INSERT` sem tal campo, ou poderia usar o [`DEFAULT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/data-type-defaults.html) ao invés do valor.

---

### Definir na inserção, ainda no PHP:

```
$mensagem = $_POST['mensagem2'] ?? 'Sem mensagem';
$mensagem = mysqli_real_query($con, $mensagem);
```

Se tiver usando alguma versão antiga do PHP poderia também fazer:

```
$mensagem = isset($_POST['mensagem2']) ? $_POST['mensagem2'] : 'Sem mensagem';
$mensagem = mysqli_real_query($con, $mensagem);
```

---

### Tratar a exibição do texto, no PHP:

Insira o texto em branco, normalmente no MySQL e trata isto na saída:

```
mysqli_query('SELECT * FROM denuncia ...');
//...

if($ResultadoDaQuery['mensagem'] === ''){
    $ResultadoDaQuery['mensagem'] = 'Sem mensagem';
}

//...
```

Isso iria substituir o texto na hora de mostrar, logicamente existe outras formas de fazer essa substituição.

---

### Tratar a exibição do texto, no MySQL:

Como na forma anterior, porém fazendo com que o trabalho seja do MySQL:

```
SELECT IF(mensagem = '', 'Sem mensagem', mensagem) as mensagem FROM denuncia
```

Essa query irá fazer com que a mensagem "Sem mensagem" seja retornada caso a mensagem seja em branco.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer uma checagem simples para isso ao declarar a variável `$mensagem`:

```
$mensagem = $_POST["mensagem2"] == "" ? $_POST["mensagem2"] : "Sem Mensagem";
```